# Remove custom table filter based on input value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JS function that filters data for me based on a drop-down menu, which has all values from table and it works just fine.

I would like to have an 'All' value and if users select the value, it will show all values/remove the filter.

The below function does not work, it shows nothing if I select "All". Could you advise me, how to achieve this, please?

```js
/* Drop-down function */
function categoriesFilter() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("categories");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("repositoryReports");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  if (filter != "All") {
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <table id="repositoryReports" class="repository-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Category<br><br>
        <select class="drop-down" id="categories" onchange="categoriesFilter()">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Test 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Test 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Test 7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are capitalizing the filter, so you have to check for value `ALL` after that, not `All`. Secondly, you need to remove thee display style none when the filter ALL is used. Try the snippet below:

```js
    /* Drop-down function */
    function categoriesFilter() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("categories");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("repositoryReports");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || filter === "ALL") {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }       
            }
      }
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<table id="repositoryReports" class="repository-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Category<br><br>
                    <select class="drop-down" id="categories" onchange="categoriesFilter()">
                        <option>All</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test 1</td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Test 2</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Test 3</td>
            </tr>
       <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Test 4</td>
            </tr>
       <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Test 5</td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Test 6</td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Test 7</td>
            </tr>
                
         </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show all rows when the `All` option is selected you can simply adjust your `if` condition to check for that value when setting the rows to a visible state.

Note in the example below that I made some changes to the logic to make it more succinct and in line with modern standards, specifically removing the inline `onchange` attribute for an unobtrusive event handler.

```js
let table = document.querySelector("#repositoryReports");
let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

document.querySelector('#categories').addEventListener('change', e => {
  let filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  rows.forEach(tr => {
    let td = tr.querySelector('td'); // gets the first match only
    tr.style.display = (filter === "ALL" || (td && td.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter))) ? 'table-row' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="repositoryReports" class="repository-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Category<br><br>
        <select class="drop-down" id="categories">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
          <option>7</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Test 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Test 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Test 7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, this example assumes that the table content is static. If it gets dynamically updated you will need to move the `table` and `rows` variable definitions *inside* the `change` event handler.